# Transaction log reported full but is not

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Batch jobs error emails report:

> The transaction log for database 'WebDB' is full.

No, it isn't. Its 90% free. The transaction log backups run normally. My hardware guy tells me the hardware is running perfectly, with plenty of space. SQL Server 2008 SP3, but not R2.

I'm a developer, we no longer have a DBA. So it falls to me to try and fix this.

Comment: Maybe a large transaction would have exceeded the transaction log's space but was aborted before it wrote anything to the log.

Comment: *At the time* the batch job emailed you, the log *was* full.  If you have ongoing log backups, by the time you look at it the log may no longer *be* full.

Comment: That scenarios is possible. But not in this case. I'm getting many repeats of the same message throughout the day, while looking at all the empty space available for the logs.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes has the right idea most likely. Whatever caused the error message probably rolled back and thus by the time you got to it, the log reported adequate free space. Check your logs to see what may have failed.

Comment: The batch is only dropping tables, so the batch itself is not so large as to overrun the log during execution.

Comment: Increase the size of the log file by, say, 20% and see what happens.

Comment: Are your log files not set to autogrow?

Comment: I would also see autogrowth for log file. Make sure it not in percentage causing unnecessary growth

Answer (score 5):

In all probability you had a large transaction that filled up your transaction log.  When the transaction failed it rolled back.  This cleared up your transaction log.

If that particular transaction needs to be processed then you can either

- Modify your log size and max log size - This is best if this is a regular process.  Running a transaction log backup right afterwards is not a bad idea either.
- Change the code to reduce the amount of transaction space needed.  This could be by using a minimally logged operation or by doing several smaller transactions (with a transaction backup in the middle).

Comment: Additionally, you may want to ensure you don't have VLFs that are overly large as that could prevent log reuse.  Probably not the case, but might be worth looking at if everything else looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Olivier was correct, but there was an additional factor: I have learned that DROP TABLE (and also TRUNCATE TABLE) is indeed logged, it just gets logged on a slightly different schedule, and without quite as much detail as individual record record changes. So this process could indeed have been filling the log, and then the error resulted in a a rollback to the logs too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that SQL Server will reserve [space](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/merrill_aldrich/archive/2012/06/12/t-sql-tuesday-31-paradox-of-the-sawtooth-log.aspx) in the transaction file in case it needs to perform a roll back. If the roll back could be large e.g. a whole table, this reservation may overflow the log without actually writing any log records.